# Use a metaclass's __getattribute__ method to modify the returned attributes

Tags: python, metaprogramming, decorator

I'm trying to implement* a class/type to use as an enumerator for the keys to `dict`s.  I want to modify the attribute values returned, for example, for a custom class:

```
class TestKeys(Keys):
    one = 1
    two = 2
```

instead of having `TestKeys.one` return `1`, I want to override it to return something like, (the *string*) `"TestKeys.one"`.  I've tried doing the following, but it falls into an infinite recursion...

```
class _Keys_Meta(type):
    # Store all attribute values to list ``__values__``
    #     (if they dont start with '__')                                                                                                                     
    def __init__(self, name, bases, dict):
        self.__init__(self)
        self.__values__ = [ self.__dict__.values()[ii] for ii,ent 
                            in enumerate(self.__dict__)
                            if not ent.startswith('__') ]

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):                                                                                                                                                                       
        if( not hasattr(self, '__values__') ): 
            self.__values__ = []                                                                                                                                         
        if( attr in self.__values__ ): 
            return "{:s}.{:s}".format(self.__name__, str(attr))                                                                                                                                                
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)

class Keys(object):
    __metaclass__ = _Keys_Meta
```

**How can I modify the values returned when an attribute is accessed?**

---

*I am familiar with [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), but I don't like some of its features.

Comment: Assuming line 5 is supposed to be indented further, you are calling `self.__init__` on the current object while inside `self.__init__`. You don't need to do that,` __init__` is called automatically. 

You can also drop the parens around your if statements, they're unnecessary.

Comment: *"I don't like some of its features"* - which? Have you looked into its implementation to see how you could modify it accordingly?

Comment: @jesseroberts, IIRC from testing this --- the `self.__init__` is run ***after*** the metaclass `__init__` which means that the attributes I'm storing to `__values__` won't be set yet.  Re if-statements... I like the parentheses.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, mostly I want the resulting values to be strings instead of objects (the objects cause trouble during debugging, and in general strings would be more convenient).  I've looked at the code... frankly its above my pay-grade.

Comment: Did you solved this somehow? It will be nice to have an answer here saying how did you solve it ...

Comment: I don't think it is possible to define `__getattribute__` in a metaclass because it will lead to infinite loop, calling `type.__getattribute__` or `super().__getattribute__` will call the metaclass that you're currently defining's `__getattribute__`. If you really want to do it, you'll have to go to writing this in C or Cython.